# Go is not found when a shell is executed on WSL starting

Tags: bash, shell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to start wsl and inject a sh to run on the starting, something like this:

`wsl --cd /path/to/script/ -e sh script.sh`

and I am getting this:
`./script.sh: 48: go: not found`

on the line 48 of the script I have this:

`go build && ./hub-api`

If I open wsl and run the script everything goes fine, but I am not able to run it on a single command.
What do I need to do to run the script on a single "line"?

Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that you're adding `go` to your path in your dotfiles, and they're not being sourced with this invocation. Using a login shell might solve it in a kinda brute-force way: `wsl --cd /path/to/script/ -e sh -l script.sh`

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `wsl --cd /path/to/script/ -e sh script.sh` and running `sh script.sh` from an interactive session is that the second case is run in a login shell.

That means that the first method does not read all your dot files, while the second does.

A simple solution is to add the `-l` option to force a login shell:

```
wsl --cd /path/to/script/ -e sh -l script.sh
```

But you may also have to use `bash -l script.sh` instead of `sh -l script` if `go` is added to your path via `~/.bash_profile` instead of `~/.profile`.

**Background info**: The kind of shell (interactive or not; login or not) you run affects which dot files get sourced when it starts. If you're using `bash`, the details are here: https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files

Comment: hi @joanis thanks for the answer, now I am getting a new error: `script.sh: 30: export: Files/PowerShell/7:/mnt/c/Python310/Scripts/:/mnt/c/Python310/:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program: bad variable name` but... line 30 on the file is empty :/ any idea of this? thanks

Comment: I have reduced the script to a simple  `echo "hola"` and I still get the same problem on the non-existent line 30... ¿¿¿???

Comment: That smells like one of your dot files has something like `export $PATH` with the $ instead of `export PATH` without it.